# Is there a difference between "artist" and "artiste"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spelling

While we commonly use the word "artist" (for a person who knows any art), a lot of literary publications and even some news organisations spell the word as "artiste" - with an "e" in the end.

Is there a difference between two words ("artist" and "artiste") or is it a US-UK English difference? If not, what's the reason for two spellings? Thank you.

Comment: "Artiste" sometimes has a negative connotation.  Particularly if the last 'teh' is highly pronounced.    In a similar way to the negative connotation of calling someone a 'Prima Donna'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*artiste* is mainly used for professional performers:

> A professional entertainer, especially a singer or dancer.

(source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/artiste))

while the word *artist* is applicable in [many more situations](https://www.lexico.com/definition/artist), e.g. hobbyists, other types of arts or even outside the arts.

As for the difference in spelling, *artiste* looks more French and hence more exclusive (at least to me). So it does not come as a surprise that it's only used for a specific group of artists.

Comment: It not only looks French but is - see the note below the link you posted!